# cookies en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Quiero meter un banner de cookies en WordPress que haga lo que tiene que hacer. He probado varios plugins, pero en todos ellos, si rechazas y refrescas no te vuelve a preguntar, con lo cual recuerda tu elección y entiendo que las ha dado como aceptadas realmente. También las aceptan al hacer clik en alguna pestaña de la web.

Esto lo he realizado en otra web con HTML5 y javascript mediante un div y dos botones

Si se hace clik en aceptar todo bien, si se hace click en rechazar se borran las cookies y por lo tanto si se refresca, se vuelve a preguntar si acepta o no.

```
const botonAceptarCookies = document.getElementById('btn-aceptar-cookies');
const avisoCookies = document.getElementById('aviso-cookies');
const fondoAvisoCookies = document.getElementById('fondo-aviso-cookies');
const botonRechazarCookies = document.getElementById('btn-configurar-cookies');


if (!localStorage.getItem('cookies-aceptadas')) {
avisoCookies.classList.add('activo');
fondoAvisoCookies.classList.add('activo');
} else {
 dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'cookies-aceptadas' });
}

botonAceptarCookies.addEventListener('click', () => {
gtag('consent', 'update', {
    'ad_storage': 'granted',
    'analytics_storage': 'granted'
});

avisoCookies.classList.remove('activo');
fondoAvisoCookies.classList.remove('activo');
localStorage.setItem('cookies-aceptadas', true);
dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'cookies-aceptadas' });
location.reload();
});

botonRechazarCookies.addEventListener('click', borrarCookie);


function borrarCookie() {

var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {

    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    var nombreCookie = c.substring(0, c.indexOf("="));
    console.log("Cookies rechazadas y borradas");
    document.cookie = nombreCookie + "=" + ";" + "max-age=0";
    avisoCookies.classList.remove('activo');
    fondoAvisoCookies.classList.remove('activo');
    localStorage.setItem('cookies-rechazadas', true);

    dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'cookies-rechazadas' });

  }
  return null;

  }
```

No se como hacer esto en WordPress para crear un banner en condiciones que acepte si acepto, y rechace si no acepto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto lo puedes hacer con javascript, asumamos que tenemos dos botones.

```
<a href="#" id="aceptar">
<a href="#" id="rechazar">
```

Entonces solo debes de detectar con javascript cuando se hace click en uno u otro, como estas usando wordpress la forma más facil es usar jQuery.

Por ejemplo, tengo este codigo para crear una cookie.

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if ( nDays == null || nDays == 0 ) {
        nDays=1;
    }
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape( cookieValue ) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
}
```

Entonces voy a crear la cookie al presionar aceptar.

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#aceptar', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    SetCookie( 'mi-cookie', true, 7 );
});
```

Ahora, para hacer que se borren las cookies solo debes de saber el nombre de la cookie que quieres borrar y pasarle una fecha expirada, para que el navegador la borre, por ejemplo.

```
function removeCookie(cookieName) {
    document.cookie = "name=" + cookieName + "; expires=Sat, 20 Jan 1980 12:00:00 UTC";
}
```

Y para eliminarla al presionar el boton.

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#rechazar', function(){
    removeCookie( 'mi-cookie' );
});
```

Por ultimo, si quieres que se refresque el sitio solo agrega al final de la creación o eliminación de la cookie lo siguiente.

```
location.reload();
```

Por ejemplo

```
jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '#rechazar', function(){
    removeCookie( 'mi-cookie' );
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: entiendo! Pero donde inserto este script dentro de WordPress? Los botones están generados con un plugin de cookies y no se cual es su Id o clase tampoco. Había pensado en hacer mi propio div en html5 pero no se donde insertarlo tampoco. Imagino que modificando alguno de los documentos PHP del theme.